# plot calibration curve for machine learning

Tags: python

I have the code below and this code work only with the binary class so how can I use with three classes.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scikitplot as skp


orgnal_data = pd.read_excel("movie.xls")

# Program extracting first column
text = orgnal_data.iloc[:,0]
lable = orgnal_data.iloc[:,1]

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(fe,lable,test_size=0.30,random_state=40)


DT = DecisionTreeClassifier()
DT_y = DT.fit(x_train,y_train).predict(x_test)

clf_names = ['Decision Tree']
skp.metrics.plot_calibration_curve(y_test,DT_y,clf_names)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `scikit-plot` module, there is no function for a multiclass problem.

Read the source code [here](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot/blob/2dd3e6a76df77edcbd724c4db25575f70abb57cb/scikitplot/metrics.py#L923):

> This function currently only works for binary classification.

So you can either 1) modify the source code or 2) open a github issue and request a function for multiclass problems.

EDIT 1:

Using `scikit-learn` you have some ML models that can handle multiclass problems. For example for the `LinearSVC` function [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC), the multiclass support is handled according to a one-vs-the-rest scheme.

So you can actually have models like this and then use the `plot_calibration_curve` function for each case (one VS rest) separately.

Comment: thank you. how can I modify the function for multi-class

Comment: if I have decision tree and naive bays how can I use a calibration curve

Comment: multiclass of binary?

Comment: how can i make it??